# Cross tabulation to include 2 other variables in the body of the crosstab

Tags: r, pivot-table

Consider these data:

```
     y b1 b2  M
1  143  1  1  B
2  152  2  1  D
3  199  3  1  A
4  155  4  1  C
5  161  1  2  D
6  166  2  2  B
7  198  3  2  C
8  195  4  2  A
9  193  1  3  A
10 154  2  3  C
11 151  3  3  B
12 150  4  3  D
13 160  1  4  C
14 176  2  4  A
15 159  3  4  D
16 120  4  4  B
```

I would like to cross tabulate by b1 and b2. and each cell in the table should contain the  combination of M and y, like this:

```
                  b2
         1       2      3      4
    1  B 143   D 161  A 193  C 160  
b1  2  D 152   B 166  C 154  A 176
    3  A 199   C 198  B 151  D 159
    4  C 155   A 195  D 150  B 120
```

(I did this by hand so hopefully there won't be a mistake !)

Is there a one-liner to do this in R ?

Answer (score 3):

R does not accept Multiindexing. The best way you could get something close to your problem is by using `reshape`:

```
reshape(df, v.names=c("M", "y"), timevar = "b2", dir="wide", idvar = "b1", sep="_")

  b1 M_1 y_1 M_2 y_2 M_3 y_3 M_4 y_4
1  1   B 143   D 161   A 193   C 160
2  2   D 152   B 166   C 154   A 176
3  3   A 199   C 198   B 151   D 159
4  4   C 155   A 195   D 150   B 120
```

---

if you have `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = b2, values_from = c(M,y), names_vary = 'slowest')

# A tibble: 4 × 9
     b1 M_1     y_1 M_2     y_2 M_3     y_3 M_4     y_4
  <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 B       143 D       161 A       193 C       160
2     2 D       152 B       166 C       154 A       176
3     3 A       199 C       198 B       151 D       159
4     4 C       155 A       195 D       150 B       120
```

You could then coerce the `b1` column to be the rownames using `column_to_rownames` function

Answer (score 1):

Hackish, and error-prone:

```
x <- xtabs(y ~ b1 + b2 , data = df)
x[seq(nrow(df))] <- with(df, paste(M, y))
```

gives

```
> x
   b2
b1  1     2     3     4    
  1 B 143 D 161 A 193 C 160
  2 D 152 B 166 C 154 A 176
  3 A 199 C 198 B 151 D 159
  4 C 155 A 195 D 150 B 120
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "y b1 b2  M
1  143  1  1  B
2  152  2  1  D
3  199  3  1  A
4  155  4  1  C
5  161  1  2  D
6  166  2  2  B
7  198  3  2  C
8  195  4  2  A
9  193  1  3  A
10 154  2  3  C
11 151  3  3  B
12 150  4  3  D
13 160  1  4  C
14 176  2  4  A
15 159  3  4  D
16 120  4  4  B", h = TRUE)
```